#  Why $z \in \overline{A}$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In the Picture blew:[image]
The paper can be downloaded [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-08/S0002-9939-99-04783-8/). Why $z \in \overline{A}$?
Thanks.

A point $x$ of a space $X$ is called $G_\omega$-separated from a subset $Y$ of $X$ if there is a closed $G_\omega$ -set $P$ in $X$ such that $x \in P$ and the sets $Y$ and $P$ are disjoint.

Comment: Downvoted, although I haven't voted to close (yet).

Comment: Given the existing votes to close, I suggest that discussion (about closing or keeping open this question) takes place at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1539/not-sure-what-to-make-of-all-these-posts/

Comment: @Yemon Choi: You are not very welcome. It seems that you only can do this, what other could you do?

Comment: @Luke: perhaps you would get a better reception if you gave some explanation of why you have posted so many questions in general topology, often in complicated areas but with the questions usually seeming to have quick answers

Comment: Speaking for myself: I'm afraid I don't react well to someone who uses to different names on different sites, and in neither case is upfront about their motivation for questions or previous experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something because this is quite elementary, but:

Since $Z$ is regular, for any open neighborhood $U$ of $z$ there is an open $V$ such that $z\in V$ and $\overline{V}\subseteq U$  (apply regularity to $z$ and the complement of $U$).  Do this countably many times and take intersection, and you'll find that for any open neighborhood $U$ of $z$ there is a closed $G_\omega$-set $P$ such that $z\in P\subseteq U$.

If follows easily that if  $z$ is not $G_\omega$-separated from $A$ (that is, if (b) fails), then $z$ must be in the closure of $A$.

Comment: You may find http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1539/not-sure-what-to-make-of-all-these-posts/#Item_0 provides some background

Comment: @Todd Eisworth: How could you see that $\cap V_i$ is closed as a closed $G_\omega$-set $P$ of $z$?

Comment: The nesting guarantees that the intersection of the V_i is the same as the intersection of their closures, hence closed.

Comment: That is, you make sure $V_{i+1}\subseteq\overline{V}_{i+1}\subseteq V_i$, and then $\cap V_i = \cap \overline{V}_i$ is closed and a $G_\omega$ set.

Comment: @Todd Eisworth: Yes. I got it. Thanks!